# django MultiValueDictKeyError when trying to retrieve "type"

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have a django page that exports the contents of a list to a csv. The filename is set up to include the organization name, but I want it to also include the type of file as well. As far as I can tell, the values are being pulled from here:

```
<div class="p-1 col-12 fw-bold mb-2">
                    <label class="text-r mb-1">Select File Type:</label>
                    <select name="type" class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                        <option value="accounts">Accounts</option>
                        <option value="contacts">Contacts</option>
                        <option value="membership">Membership</option>
                        <option value="cg">Community Group</option>
                        <option value="cgm">Community Group Member</option>
                        <option value="so">Sales Order</option>
                        <option value="item">Item</option>
                        <option value="event">Event</option>
                        <option value="tt">Ticket Type</option>
                        <option value="si">Schedule Item</option>
                        <option value="attendee">Attendee</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="p-1 col-12 fw-bold mb-2">
                    <label class="text-r mb-1">Organization Name:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Organization Name" type="text" name="name" required />
                </div>
```

The python function that calls it is as follows:

```
class CsvView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        output = io.BytesIO()
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        data = request.POST["raees"]
        name = request.POST["name"]
        d_type = request.POST["type"]
        data = list(data.split(","))
        last = data[-1]
        first = data[0]
        data[0] = first.replace("[", "")
        data[-1] = last.replace("]", "")
        row = 0
        col = 0
        for i in data:
            i = i.replace("'", "")
            worksheet.write(row, col, i)
            row = row + 1
        workbook.close()
        output.seek(0)
        filename = f"{name} {d_type} Issue Tracker.xlsx"
        response = HttpResponse(
            output,
            content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        )
        response["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
        return response
```

The **name = request.POST["name"]** part seems to work ok, but not the **d_type = request.POST["type"]** part that I added. I also tried d_type = request.POST.get("type"), to no avail. The first one gets me the error indicated in the title but the latter code (as well as **d_type = request.GET.get("type")** just do not pull the value when needed. There's a previous function that does call "type" without any problems so I'm not sure what's needed here. Any help would be appreciated.

(If you're wondering about this 'previous function' that calls "type", it's as follows):

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, "myapp/file-form.html")

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        type = request.POST["type"]
        file = request.FILES['file'].name
        # file = request.FILES["file"].read().decode("utf-8")
        name = request.POST["name"]
        # dataset = Dataset().load(file, format="csv")
        dataset = pd.read_csv(request.FILES['file'], encoding = "ISO-8859-1")

        if type == "accounts":
            errors = accounts_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "contacts":
            errors = contacts_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "membership":
            errors = member_ship_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "cg":
            errors = cg_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "cgm":
            errors = cgm_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "so":
            errors = so_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "item":
            errors = item_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "event":
            errors = event_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "tt":
            errors = tt_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "si":
            errors = si_checker(dataset)
        elif type == "attendee":
            errors = att_checker(dataset)
        context = {
            "results": errors,
            "name": name,
        }
        return render(request, "myapp/results.html", context=context)
```

Comment: I would start by checking, what is actually the data posted. You can add a simple print(request.data) to the beginning of your view, then start the debug server on the console (`python manage.py runserver`) and check what is posted. If type is not in there, the issue is in your html.

Comment: `type` is a reserved keyword, so you might want to rename your variable to file_type or something to avoid any undefined behaviour.

Comment: That's the interesting thing. I figured as much, which is why I changed my variable to "d_type". Nevertheless, the last code example seems to use "type" without problems.

Comment: The code seems ok for your purposes. My next guess would be there is a typo of some sort in your form definition. You can try logging the whole POST form (with a print, logging or using debugger) to see what's in the dictionary. That should give you the info necessary to resolve the issue.

Comment: As previously said by treuss and Jesse, it looks that you have a typo somewhere in the HTML file. Do a search (CTRL+F / grep) for *type*.

Comment: what method you're using to send this data to the view side? ajax calls or Form submission? i tried your code with form submission i got the type value with `request.POST['type']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this as an alternative if you can't find the bug:

```
#your Forms.py
from django import forms
my_d_types=(("accounts","Accounts"),("contacts","Contacts"),
            ("membership","Membership"),("cg","Community Group"),
            ("cgm","Community Group Member"),("so","Sales Order"),
            ("item","Item"),("event","Event"),("tt","Ticket Type"),
            ("si","Schedule Item"),("attendee","Attendee")
            )

class CsvViewForm(forms.Form): 
        #include this to replace existing 'd_type' variable in your form related to the CsvView
        d_type=forms.ChoiceField(label='Select File Type:',choices=my_d_types,required=False)

#yourfile.HTML
#replace the section <select .... </select> with the following
 <div>           
    <p>{{ form.d_type.label_tag }}</p>
    <p>{{ form.d_type }}</p>
</div>

#your Views.py
from .forms import CsvViewForm

class CsvView(View):
    form = CsvViewForm(request.POST)
```

You might also check that the HTML code includes "enctype="multipart/form-data"' in the start of the form tag depending how what the rest of the file has in it, since you only showed the bit you think might have the bug.